# PySpark Json String Transformation

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I have birthday field in my dataset. I am reading data from mongodb.

schema for this is:

```
mongo_schema = StructType([
StructField("_id", StringType(), True),
StructField("birthday", StringType(), True),
# Add other fields as needed
```

])

I have data as shown in image. Now I want to extract numerical values from it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LeCc.png)

I have tried this code

```
df_extracted = df.withColumn(
'birthday_extracted',
expr("CASE WHEN get_json_object(birthday, '$.sec') IS NOT NULL THEN get_json_object(birthday, '$.sec') " 
     "WHEN get_json_object(birthday, '$.sec.$numberLong') IS NOT NULL THEN get_json_object(birthday, "
     "'$.sec.$numberLong')"
     "ELSE CAST(CAST(get_json_object(birthday, '$.date') AS DOUBLE) / 1000 AS BIGINT) END"))
```

Only $.sec part of code working fine other two transformation is not working.

I need help for this transformation.